# Is it necessary that class className must be coded in className.java?

Tags: java, syntax

I'm using maven to build the project and compile failed because I put class `Test2` in `Test.java`,

but is it because of maven or simply because java itself doesn't support this?

BTW,how can I open a maven project with eclipse?

Comment: No idea about Maven but the class name should match that of compilation unit (^.java) or else this will cause a failure.

Comment: In addition, a class name should start with a capital letter.

Comment: Please ask only one question at a time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A `public` class called `ClassName` must (in most cases) be defined in a file called `ClassName.java`.

**Edit**

Although this is not a requirement of the Java language, most (if not all) implementations of Java, the above mentioned relationship between the class name and file name must hold, or a compiler error will result.

(For more information, please refer to [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843438/is-it-necessary-that-class-classname-must-be-coded-in-classname-java/2843544#2843544).)

The reason for this can be found by reading [Section 7.2: Packages](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.2) of [The Java Language Specification, Third Edition](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/j3TOC.html).

In the section, it describes how the directory structure can be mapped to a [fully-qualified class name](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#25430) in Java, which leads to a requirement that the `.class` file which contains the bytecode for a class must reside in a path that resembles that of the fully-qualified class name.

*The original answer which incorrectly stated that the naming scheme is a requirement has been edited.*

Answer (score 6):

The Java Language Specification itself doesn't actually *require* this - but it explicitly allows file-system-based implementations to do so, and most do.

From [section 7.6](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.6):

> When packages are stored in a file
>   system (§7.2.1), the host system may
>   choose to enforce the restriction that
>   it is a compile-time error if a type
>   is not found in a file under a name
>   composed of the type name plus an
>   extension (such as .java or .jav) if
>   either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in
>     other compilation units of the package
>     in which the type is declared.
> - The
>     type is declared public (and therefore
>     is potentially accessible from code in
>     other packages).
>
> This restriction
>   implies that there must be at most one
>   such type per compilation unit. This
>   restriction makes it easy for a
>   compiler for the Java programming
>   language or an implementation of the
>   Java virtual machine to find a named
>   class within a package; for example,
>   the source code for a public type
>   wet.sprocket.Toad would be found in a
>   file Toad.java in the directory
>   wet/sprocket, and the corresponding
>   object code would be found in the file
>   Toad.class in the same directory.
>
> When packages are stored in a database
>   (§7.2.2), the host system must not
>   impose such restrictions. In practice,
>   many programmers choose to put each
>   class or interface type in its own
>   compilation unit, whether or not it is
>   public or is referred to by code in
>   other compilation units.

For *practical* purposes I think it's reasonable to basically assume that it's required.

Answer (score 2):

Java requires you to have your public class inside a file with the same name.

For eclipse and maven use [sonatype m2](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) plugin. Inside your maven project you can then type

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse
```

and maven will create a `.project` and a `.classpath` file for you. These are the files eclipse needs to work with the project.

You have to define the eclipse classpath variable `M2_REPO` with the path of your local maven repository.

With sonatype m2 you can do maven things from within eclipse: add dependencies, run maven targets, ...

Comment: The m2eclipse plugin has **nothing** to do with the maven-eclipse-plugin. If you use the former, you don't have to run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. If you use the later, you don't have to use m2eclipse.

Comment: Seems I can directly run `mvn eclipse:eclipse ` without installing sonatype me plugin?

Comment: @pascal-thivent: Yes, you are totally right. I added m2 because it makes things easier in eclipse. But I missed to say that these are two distinct topics.

Comment: @httpinterpret: Yes, you can.

Comment: But I got an unbound classpath variable error in eclipse:`M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar`...And in `.project` there is a comment saying `NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.`

Comment: Inside eclipse you have to define a classpath variable `M2_REPO` that points to your local maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm using maven to build the project and compile failed because I put class Test2 in Test.java,

Source files must be named after the *public class* they contain, appending the suffix `.java`. In you case, the source file for the public class `Test2` must be `Test2.java` <sup>1</sup>.

> is it because of maven or simply because java itself doesn't support this?

The Java compiler, `javac`, is complaining, not Maven (Maven doesn't change the behavior of the compiler).

> how can I open a maven project with eclipse?

Either use the [Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) (i.e. a plugin for Maven) and simply run `mvn eclipse:eclipse` on your project and then **Import...** it as **Existing Projects into Workspace** in Eclipse. You will need to set a classpath variable M2_REPO pointing to the local repository to use it. Check the [Usage](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/usage.html#Maven%20repository) page for the details.

Or (and that's an **exclusive** or) install [m2eclipse](http://m2eclipse.sonatype.org/) (i.e. a plugin for Eclipse that extends it to make it able to understand a Maven projects and interact with it in a bi-directional way) and **Import...** your project as an **Existing Maven Projects**.

If EXCLUSIVE is not clear enough, this means: use one **or** the other but not both in the same time.

<sup>1</sup> As mentioned by Jon Skeet, the JLS *allows* this restriction for file-based implementations. This doesn't apply when using a database to store Java constructs (like Visual Age for Java was doing). But in your case, it does.

Comment: I don't think the m2eclipse will work because there is such a comment in the generated `.project`.

Comment: `<comment>NO_M2ECLIPSE_SUPPORT: Project files created with the maven-eclipse-plugin are not supported in M2Eclipse.</comment>`

Comment: @httpinterpret I explicitly wrote that they are EXCLUSIVE, you use one or the other, not both in the same time. I can't be clearer, just read carefully.

Comment: oops,you are right:) Finally,do you know where is the classpath variable `M2_REPO` restored? I don't see the definition in either `.project` or `.classpath`.

Comment: @httpinterpret I don't know where it is physically stored exactly but it's available via Windows > Preferences > Java > Build Path > Classpath Variables.

Answer (score 0):

The connection between file name and class name is the following:

- if you have `public class` in a file, the filename must be the same as the class name
- you can have as many non-public classes as you want in a file with different names