# Very Basic Java

Tags: java

I'm very new to Java. Here is my code:

```
public class funk {

  int largest(int a,int b,int c) 
  {

    if(a>b)
    { 
      if(a>c)
      {
        return a;
      }
      else if(b>c)
      {
        return b;
      }
    else 
    {
      return c;
    }
  }
}

public class firstprog {

  public static  void main(String args[]) {

    int a=7;
    int b=8;
    int c=9;
    funk punk=new funk();
    System.out.println(punk.largest(a,b,c));
    
  }

}
```

The error that Eclipse gives me is **The public type funk must be defined in its own file**.

Why is this so?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it necessary that class className must be coded in className.java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2843438/is-it-necessary-that-class-classname-must-be-coded-in-classname-java)

Comment: @Joachim that's not really a dupe.  Anant didn't say what he named his file, but it can't have more than one class declared as shown.

Comment: I would just like to state that class-names in Java should always (it's a best practice) start with an uppercase character.

Comment: As an exercise for the reader, there are trivial recursive/iterative versions that will handle any number of inputs.

Comment: It seems like the question has been modified to match the answer

Comment: I rolled back your edit. Please do not change your question like this, if it completely changes the context. OItherwise, the given answers don't make sense anymore. If you still have problems, please post a new question instead.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that this question is 9 years old. I assumed it is new, because It just popped up due to recent activity. I reverted my rollback to not create any more confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the problem is that you can only have one public class per file and this file should have the same name than the class. You can just remove the public in front of the definition of the first class. **A better way to do** would be to make it a static method of the main class.

To solve you second problem you can do this:

```
public class firstprog {


    public static int largest(int a,int b,int c) 
    {
        if(a>b)
        { 
            if(a>c)
                return a;
            else 
                if(b>c)
                    return b;
                else 
                    return c;
        }
        else
        {
            if(b>c)
                return b;
            else 
                return c;
        }
    }   

    public static  void main(String args[]) {

        int a=19;
        int b=2;
        int c=1;

        System.out.println(largest(a,b,c));  
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for that. I still get an error though, which is : **this method must return a result of type int** - here the method being talked about , is the method  funk()

Comment: @Anant: ask yourself: what does it return if `a` is *not* `> b`? A method must return a value in *each possible path* (except where it throws an exception).

Comment: @Ic2817: only one public *top-level* class per file.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes it should, i was basically testing out the syntax of my code

Comment: @Anant: not just "should": the compiler won't let you compile it if it doesn't!

Comment: @JoachimSauer I didn't save that the other class has to be public but you are right.

Comment: @lc2817 - *smack* - **NEVER** use conditional statements _without_ the brackets (`{}`).  Especially if you use it for higher-level groupings.  And, regardless of the specific style of bracket placement, they aren't consistently indented - this can be/is very confusing.

Comment: @X-Zero I don't really agree with you on that. The good idea would be to use a build-in function to do that. But anyway I think that it is not mandatory to but brackets to be clear. I corrected my indentation that was indeed wrong, thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @lc2817 I make the same mistake all the time ;)

Answer (score 2):

Only one public top level class (a top level class is a class not contained in another class) is allowed per .java file.

Define `funk` in funk.java with no other top level classes.

Put any other top level classes in their own files where the file name matches the class name.

Regarding your second question, if you declare a method to return a particular type, like `int`, then all paths through that method must result in a `return` statement returning a valid value.  In your example, the `if` statement might not be entered!

What happens if `b == a` or `a < b`?

Comment: In that case I don't see the purpose of defining it in a separate file.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen Why would you do so? Do you deem that it is a good practice?

Comment: Separating classes into different files? Yes, I deem that good practice

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to put multiple classes into one file? Each class should get its own .java file with the appropriate name. Also make the first letter of your class upper case, as this is the naming convention.

As an aside, your function will only work if a is larger than c. You've missed out on some cases.

EDIT: you can have nested classes, but I think you might want to stay away from stuff like that for now.

Answer (score 1):

In Java public classes must be in separate files with name the same as class name.

So put your funk class in funk.java file and firstprog class in firstprog.java file
Or delete `public` in funk class, then this class will have default package modifier.

Answer (score 0):

For your second error, the logic seems to be off a little... there is no return statement in the case where b > a.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is this so?

If you mean "why do I get this error", it's because you have not put the class in its own file, and you must. If you mean "why must I put the class in its own file", it's because Java says so: one `public` type (class or interface) per file.

Specifically, "its own" file must have the same name: the `public class funk` goes in `funk.java`, and the `public class firstprog` goes in `firstprog.java`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class firstprog {

    public static int largest(int a,int b,int c) 
    {

         if(a>b)
         { 
              if(a>c)
              {
                  return a;
              }
              else if(b>c)
              {
                  return b;
              }
              else
              {
                  return c;
              }
         }
         return 0;
    }   

    public static  void main(String args[]) {

        int a=7;
        int b=8;
        int c=9;

        System.out.println(largest(a,b,c));

    }
}
```

Note:  you have to add return statement, because a is not greater then b, so it it not going inside of if block.. In your larget(...) it is expecting return statement as int.. so you have to add one more return statement.  then it work ... Cheers ...!!!

Comment: Yes, he needs to add a `return` statement at the end.  However, returning `0` is _not_ the correct answer - _especially_ if all of the inputs are greater than that...

Answer (score 0):

During compilation time, your compiler cannot find the parallel else condition of (a>b) that is => **if(a<=b)**

what it will return if your input matches this block?
So you should provide this

Answer (score 0):

This Eclipse error has already been answered by other users. Anyway here is an alternative to find the largest number of type int

**Alternative - Find the largest integer, using stream():**

```
public static int largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    return Arrays.asList(a, b, c).stream().max(Integer::compareTo).get().intValue();
}
```

**Summary of the error:**

Here is the Eclipse error:

```
The method must return a result of type int
```

**Reson for error:**

Not all condition are taken care of in method largest. "Outside" condition 'if(a > b)' a "return an int" is needed.

**Alernative - 'if statements' using Clean code's concept 'early return'/'eager return':**

```
public static int largest(int a, int b, int c) {
    if(a > b && a > c) {
        return a;
    }

    if(b > c) {
        return b;
    }

    return c;
}
```