# Cant find the mistake

Tags: java, methods

The task was to write a method to return the least value of an array.
Would someone quickly look over my code?

```
public static int findMinimum (int [] array) {  
    for (int kohlrabi = 0; kohlrabi < array.length; kohlrabi++) {                           
         for (int zwiebel= 0; zwiebel < array.length; zwiebel ++) {                                         
                if (array [zwiebel] < array [kohlrabi]) {                                   
                    kohlrabi = zwiebel -1;
                    break;  
                }                                                                                       
                int spinat = array [kohlrabi];                      
                if (zwiebel == array.length-1) {
                    return spinat;  
                }
         }  
    }

}
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problem:      This method must return a result of type int
>       at Abgabe7.ArrayExercises.findMinimum(ArrayExercises.java:38)

It's a homework for my school and I definitely understood the logic behind it but cannot find my fault.
Thanks Max

Comment: The error is because the compiler doesn't know whether `if(zwiebel == array.length-1)` will ever be true. If it never evaluates to true, there will be no return statement.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resolving “The method must return a result of type int” in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7996632/resolving-the-method-must-return-a-result-of-type-int-in-java) and others. First tip: when you don’t understand an error message, paste it into your search engine.

Comment: I'm honestly really confused about how you came up with this algorithm.. why not just `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; for(int num : array) if(num < min) min = num; return min;`?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have two loops.  One loop would work.

Simply loop though the array keeping a variable which is the lowest you've found.

Comment: The code should theoretacly work,- meens I dont get why it doesnt

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a global variable before the loop then use only one for loop in your code as follows:

```
int zwiebel= 0;
for (int kohlrabi = 0; kohlrabi < array.length; kohlrabi++) { 
    if (kohlrabi == 0){
        zwiebel = array[kohlrabi];
    }
    if (array[kohlrabi] < zwiebel) { 
        zwiebel = array[kohlrabi];
    }
}
```

The lowest value in your array is now stored in the variable `zwiebel`.

Comment: Thx for taking ur time. I see what ur doing. The code was a logical mistake of mine.

Answer (score 0):

The real mistake is that you are not taking the possibility of an empty array into account. One thing to learn in programming is to think of all possibilities (maybe you’ve discovered that already). An array in Java (and most other languages) can have length 0, that is, have no elements in it. When `array.length` is 0, your outer for loop doesn’t execute, so we get down to the bottom of the method without having returned anything and without having anything to return.

Java is dumb, but nevertheless smart enough to discover this problem for you. When your method is declared to return an `int`, it insists that it too can see that it will return an `int` in all cases. In your method it cannot, which is what the following message is trying to tell you:

> This method must return a result of type int

One possible fix — and I may be showing you something that you haven’t learned in school yet — is to insert the following statement in the end of your method:

```
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find the minimum of an empty array");
```

Throwing an exception is an alternative to returning a value, so this statement will make Java happy. If you actually try to find the minimum of an empty array, your program will crash and give you the message “Cannot find the minimum of an empty array”. But finding the minimum of an array that has numbers in it should work now.

That said the others are correct: Your way of finding the minimum is overly complex. I have been staring at your code and still have not understood how it works. Such code is not good. In real life you will be writing code that others will need to read and change after you, and no one can change code they don’t understand, so your code would not be useful. More important than writing code that works correctly is writing readable code.

**Edit:** There are variations on how to do this in a simple way. For a school exercise using a `for` loop I would write:

```
public static int findMinimum (int [] array) {
    if (array.length == 0) {
        return 42; // or whichever value is desired in this case
    }
    int niedrichsteSoWeit = array[0];
    for (int index = 1; index < array.length; index++) {                           
        if (array[index] < niedrichsteSoWeit) {
            niedrichsteSoWeit = array[index];
        }
    }
    return niedrichsteSoWeit;
}
```

For production code I probably would not write a method but use the built-in functionality, for example:

```
    IntStream.of(myIntArray)
            .min()
            .ifPresentOrElse(min -> {
                // do something with min
            }, () -> {
                // do whatever you want to do when the array is empty
            });
```

Don’t worry if you don’t understand a bit of this snippet. It’s mostly for more experienced programmers who might happen to read this answer.

Comment: Thx for taking time! I put a return on the bottom of the method and now it works. Thx for that. I just dont get why this code should be overly complex. I dont see any other way to do it.

Comment: I had an logical mistake. Thats why it's so overly complex. Thx